# HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization is null?

Tags: authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I get the token and add it to the Authorization header of the injected HttpClient:

```
    public MyAuthenticationService(HttpClient globalHttpClient)
    {
        _globalHttpClient = globalHttpClient;
    }

    public void Login(..)
    {
        ..
        ((AuthStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).NotifyUserAuthentication(token);
        AddAccessTokenToHttpClientHeader(token);
    }

    private void AddAccessTokenToHttpClientHeader(string accessToken)
    {
        _globalHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    }
```

So far so good, I checked and the token and headers are set. But then my first api call in another service:

```
var test = _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization; // test is null!
return await ApiUtils.GetList<T>(_httpClient, uri, _logger); // Error: 401
```

Is this a different HttpClient or something? I injected it normally. In Startup.cs I have this line:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work but it's far from ideal. I set the render-mode in _Host.cshtml to:

```
render-mode="Server"
```

and then I set it manually:

```
string? token = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(Constants.LocalStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
if (!HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization") || HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization == null)
                HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
return await ApiUtils.StaticConsumeGetList<T>(HttpClient, uri, _logger);
```

I'm hoping someone has a better solution.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, this works completely differently on Blazor Server compared to WASM. **You cannot (and probably should not) retrieve the tokens from LocalStorage in OnAfterRenderAsync()** so you must add and get the authentication from&to the HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext instead using middleware. This however creates the issue that new tabs and closing the browser also kills your login session but this is the intended way for Blazor Server applications. Login sessions should not be kept for multiple days. This method also preserves your prerender mode.